# c# - create thread in for loop (arguement out of range exception)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I don't know how to describe this problem precisely. Let's look at my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myMT.Keys[key_indexer].Count; i++)
{
     threads.Add(new Thread(
         () =>
         {
             sounds[myMT.Keys[key_indexer][i]].PlayLooping();
         }
     ));
     threads[threads.Count - 1].Start();
}
```

**Note: sounds is a list of SoundPlayers**

The initialization of `threads and myMT`:

```
List<Thread> threads = null;
MusicTransfer myMT=null;
```

and in the constructor:

```
threads = new List<Thread>();
myMT = new MusicTransfer(bubblePanel);
```

The variable `Keys` in myMT is with type of `List<List<int>>`. It is initialized with the same way of myMT and threads. Imagine a matrix, the outer list is a list of rows and the inner one is for each cell.

When I run the program, I set `myMT.Keys[key_indexer].Count` to 1. So, normally, the for loop should stop when i reach 1.

However, it throws an exception of ArgumentOutOfRange at the line of `sounds[myMT.Keys[key_indexer][i]].PlayLooping()`. So, I used debugger to check the value of each variable.

What I found are:

1. If I use "step over" check step by step, which means time is consumed quite much after the new thread runs, for loop will stop when i reaches 1, which is the way it should be.
2. If I click "continue" after the breakpoint triggered, the for loop is still processing after i equals 1.
3. the break point should always be set at the line of `threads.Add(new Thread(`. If it is set at the line of `sounds[myMT.Keys[key_indexer][i]].PlayLooping();`, the exception will be triggered even after "step over"

I guess the problem is about thread, but have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please update your question to show how `threads` is declared and initialised. Also please update your post with **all** code that reads / writes / assigns / alters `threads`. _Do the same for `myMT` and its `Keys` property._

Comment: debug it, check your values

Comment: When your threads collection `Count` returns 0 you probably get the `Argument Out Of Range Exception`. You can use `.Start()` right after the tread's creation.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] for us to repro on our end.

Comment: Always remember to box your values.

Comment: @m.rogalski what do you mean by box?

Comment: Looks like `myMT` could be changed while the for is being looped, but your code sampple is too poor to help you, check @mjwills comment.

Comment: @JiekeWei Just change this `sounds[myMT.Keys[key_indexer][i]].PlayLooping();` to `sounds[myMT.Keys[key_indexer][(int)meIndex]].PlayLooping();` and make your first call in the loop this : `object meIndex = i;`

Comment: This code has more holes than the titanic, and its only 5 lines long

Comment: @m.rogalski what is the benifit of boxing?

Comment: @Dimitar with the help of debugger, I can see the count is already 1, so when i is 0, it pass. The problem happens when i is 1

Comment: @JiekeWei Read about boxing and how it could be useful in your case [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

Comment: @m.rogalski thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is so many things wrong with your post, however maybe this will help you out a bit

***Note*** : Make your code readable, trust me it does wonders

```
// List of threads
var threads = new List<Thread>();

// Lets stop indexing everything and make it easy for ourselves
var someList = myMT.Keys[key_indexer];

for (var i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
{
    // we need to create a reference to the indexed value
    // in the someList, otherwise there is no gaurentee
    // the thread will have the right index when it needs it 
    // (thank me later)  
    var someSound = someList[i]; 

    // create a thread and your callback
    var thread = new Thread(() => someSound.PlayLooping());

    // add thread to the list
    threads.Add(thread);
}

// now lets start the treads in a nice orderly fashion
foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Start();
}
```

Another way to do this with Tasks

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var someList = myMT.Keys[key_indexer];
for (var i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
{
    var someSound = someList[1];
    var task = new Task(() => someSound.PlayLooping());
    tasks.Add(task);
    task.Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

***Disclaimer*** : i take no responsibility for your other logic problems, this was for pure morbid academic purposes

Comment: what is the benifit of creating a variable with type var but not a specific type? If it is about "boxing", I am reading the page that @m.rogalski provides me. And thanks for help! I am just a student learning coding.

Comment: @JiekeWei The type is implicit i.e the compiler knows what it is, and so do you, so why not make the code readable

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed my thread list with task list and it works good (though I still don't know what is wrong with threads). And I agree with your coding format, it is more readable